# How do I make my cats scratch their scratching posts?

Tags: cats, scratching

I bought scratching posts but only 1 of my cat bother scratching it.

They instead scratch my expensive furniture. So what should I do?

Put Catnip?

Answer (score 2):

Buy another scratching post, this one should be more expensive than the first one. Then he will start using the cheap scratching post.

Jokes aside, you can't tell a cat what to do. What has helped me over the years is, putting some catnip over the post, so it feels more appealing to the cat. Also, try scratching the post yourself and whenever he uses it, try to rub him, or give him a treat, this will help him learn that its nice to use it.

Even now that my cat uses his post everyday, I try to give him some nice words when I see him do so.

It might also help putting the post near his sleep place, at least my cat, always scratches after waking up, so making it the first thing he sees when he wakes up, makes it easier for him to reach.

Another thing I've read about, but never tried personally, is spraying some lemon aroma around the furniture where you want to keep your cat away. Cats don't usually like lemon and will stay away from it.